# How to avoid duplicate values in telerik radcombobox?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, vb6, telerik

I'm using telerik Radcombobox. i'm using radcombobox itemsrequestd event handler.

```
Private Sub cbocompanyname_ItemsRequested(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs) Handles cbocompanyname.ItemsRequested
    Dim combo As RadComboBox = DirectCast(sender, RadComboBox)
    If e.Text <> "" Then
        objdbconn.OpenConn()
        Dim sql As String = "Select distinct company_gid, company_name from company_details WHERE company_name LIKE '%" + e.Text + "%'"
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt = objdbconn.GetDatatable(sql)
        objdbconn.CloseConn()
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim item As New RadComboBoxItem(row("company_name").ToString())
            combo.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my Telerik RadCombobox Design:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbocompanyname" runat="server" Width="75%" MaxLength="256" ShowToggleImage="false" Skin="WebBlue"
                                    EmptyMessage="Select Company Name/Individual Name" ItemsPerRequest="50" AllowCustomText="true" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" ZIndex="100000">
                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Here I'm checking to the company name is already exists or not.

```
 msSQL = "Select company_gid from company_details where company_name = '" & Replace(Trim(cbocompanyname.Text), "'", "'") & "'"
    objdatatable = objdbconn.GetDatatable(msSQL)
    If objdatatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        objdbconn.CloseConn()
        lblErrMsg.Text = "Company name already exists"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This is edit page. so now i want how can i check and add to the company name.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need your SQL server to return only unique records? Or you want to loop through the rows of the data table and remove duplicates? Please clarify your question and/or improve the tags I already added.

Comment: Sory, i think you understood wrong. actually i need if i enter the radcombobox it will show the data but how to allow to new data

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand